# How to split class List <> element

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

I have a class and also using List<> for multiple date

```
 public class MultipleSelect
    {
        public string Nu { get; set; }
        public string GuidID { get; set; }       
    }

MultipleSelect cs = new MultipleSelect();
List<MultipleSelect> Lst_CS = new List<MultipleSelect>();

cs = new MultipleSelect
                    {
                        GuidID = GuidID.Value.ToString(),
                        Nu = VN.ToString(),
                    };
                    Lst_CS.Add(cs);
```

And I want to separete `List<MultipleSelect>`  for  `Nu` value. It can be more than two different types of `Nu`.

if Nu value different, create a new List with Nu and GuidID value

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Sorry, what now? You want to split `Lst_CS` into different lists of type `List<MultipleSelect>`, grouped by `Nu`, is that correct?

Comment: Do you mean you want to group according to Nu (GROUP BY)? To Filter list according to Nu (WHERE)? Sorry but I can't understand the question...

Comment: You are going to have to try and phrase that a little better

Comment: Actually I dont need group by. its enough, if Nu value different, create a new List for each different Nu value

Comment: Confused? I know I am.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you need a [`Group By`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) :

```
Lst_CS.GroupBy(cs => cs.Nu);
```

You will get a list of [`IGrouping`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344977%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which is enumerable on `MultipleSelect`, with the key being the `Nu` value.

Usage :

```
foreach(var myGroup in Lst_CS.GroupBy(cs => cs.Nu))
{
    var nu = myGroup.Key;
    foreach(var multipleSelect in myGroup)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `ToDictionary()` or `GroupBy()`

Answer (score 0):

You question is very unclear, but it looks like you are trying to achieve either of these 2 options:

```
    List<string> nuList = Lst_CS.Select(x => x.Nu).ToList();
    IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, MultipleSelect>> nuGrouped = Lst_CS.GroupBy(x => x.Nu);
```